# How to access the fields in the comment reply page?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I'm using Drupal 7.

I show the form of comments in a page different from that of the nodes.

In this page, having for url mysite/comment/reply/..., I would like to modify the fields of the node which appear before the form of comments.

For example, the page looks like :

```
        Add a comment 
- 
        Title of the node  
        Field 1 of the node (display)  
        Field 2 of the node (hide) 
-
        Comment form
```

I tried to create a specific page template : page--comment--reply, but I have no access to fields and cannot thus change their appearance.

Do you know how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think comment.tpl.php is what you need

however you can also alter the display of comments in the display option on the content type.

look in "admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME/comment/display"